# iOS JSON parsing crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, crashlytics

We have a live app, integrated with Crashlytics. We are getting a rare crash reported through Crashlytics... we have never been able to replicate this in a debugger. The latest release was built in Xcode 7.x, our deployment target is iOS 6.0, and we are using ARC. Here is the relavent code:

```
+(NSString*)stringFromItems:(NSArray*)items {
    NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[items count]];
    for (MyItem* item in items) {
        [array addObject:item.dictionary];
    }

    NSData* data = nil;
    @try {
        if (![NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject: array]) {
            NSLog(@"Tried to parse invalid JSON: %@", array);
            return nil;
        }

        NSError* error = nil;
        data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:0 error:&error];
        if (!data || error) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid input array: %@ resulted in serialization error: %@", items, [error localizedDescription]);
            return nil;
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException* exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception during serialization: %@", exception);
        return nil;
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Here is the stack trace reported by Crashlytics:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000018

0  Foundation                     0x182cdcf60 _convertJSONString + 284
1  Foundation                     0x182cdc39c _writeJSONString + 124
2  Foundation                     0x182cdafbc _writeJSONValue + 116
3  Foundation                     0x182cdd394 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke + 236
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1821da44c __65-[__NSDictionaryI enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 88
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1821c80f0 -[__NSDictionaryI enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 224
6  Foundation                     0x182cdcb20 _writeJSONObject + 360
7  Foundation                     0x182cdb0d0 _writeJSONValue + 392
8  Foundation                     0x182cdd57c ___writeJSONArray_block_invoke + 144
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18217f944 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 132
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18217f7b4 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 172
11 Foundation                     0x182cdcd7c _writeJSONArray + 300
12 Foundation                     0x182cdb170 _writeJSONValue + 552
13 Foundation                     0x182cdaf00 -[_NSJSONWriter dataWithRootObject:options:error:] + 140
14 Foundation                     0x182cdbf5c +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 348
15 MyAppName                      0x1000fd104 +[MyItem stringFromItems:] (MyItem.m:232)
```

So the call to isValidJSONObject succeeded, but immediately afterwards when we try to parse the array we get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS, as if we are referencing a deallocated object (even though isValidJSONObject would have just accessed all the same objects in the array dictionaries).

I've ruled out most of the obvious answers... isValidJSONObject returns false if anything about the object is a problem (non-string keys, non JSON parseable objects like a NSDate, a NSNumber set to NaN, etc.). A duplicated key in a dictionary causes a EXC_BREAKPOINT exception in isValidJSONObject. We have not been able to come up with a scenario that would cause this specific crash.

Anyone encountered something similar? Any ideas on what might be going on? Big thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it possible that some of the dictionaries in items are mutable and being modified on another thread?

Comment: Also I don't understand ```for (MyItem* item in items) {
        [array addObject:items.dictionary];
    }``` Why would you add items.dictionary over and over again to the array? Shouldn't it be item.dictionary?

Comment: Oops... typo on my part. I've edited the post (should have been item.dictionary).

Comment: I'm seeing this happen, too, in almost identical circumstances to yours—did you ever figure out any resolution to this?

Comment: Am I glad that there are others out there seeing a similar issue :-D

Comment: We saw this issue also really rarely and also were never able to reproduce while debugging. @EricS question if the dictionary (which contains mutable dictionaries in our case) is being changed on another thread could be possible. I will try using deep copies (by archiving it with NSKeyedArchiver and unarchiving it again) and see if the error persists. 
OpusGames did you find out what happened in your case?

Comment: Did you able to find the cause of problem?

Comment: 2023, iOS 17 and Xcode 14 – the issue is still here :D